# thrift constant structure using enum

Tags: enums, constants, thrift

I've got following enum and want to create a constant map using elements of this enum:

```
enum UploadFileType {
    POPULATION,
    PROBABILITY,
    REACH,
    CMOBILE,
    CMOBAPP
}

/**
 * Defines which files are uploadable in which country
 */
const map<string,list<UploadFileType>> uploadable_files = {
    'hu': [POPULATION, PROBABILITY, REACH, CMOBILE, CMOBAPP],
    'sk': [POPULATION, PROBABILITY, REACH]
}
```

I'm getting following error here:

```
[FAILURE:/home/abc/internal.thrift:29] error: identifier POPULATION is unqualified!
[FAILURE:/home/abc/internal.thrift:29] error: identifier POPULATION is unqualified!
```

and I don't know how this should look properly.

Comment: The error says it quite accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums use dot notation:

```
const map<string,list<UploadFileType>> uploadable_files = {
    'hu': [UploadFileType.POPULATION, UploadFileType.PROBABILITY, UploadFileType.REACH, UploadFileType.CMOBILE, UploadFileType.CMOBAPP],
    'sk': [UploadFileType.POPULATION, UploadFileType.PROBABILITY, UploadFileType.REACH]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum UploadFileType {
    POPULATION,
    PROBABILITY,
    REACH,
    CMOBILE,
    CMOBAPP
}

/**
 * Defines which files are uploadable in which country
 */
const map<string,list<UploadFileType>> uploadable_files = {
    'hu': [UploadFileType.POPULATION, UploadFileType.PROBABILITY, UploadFileType.REACH, UploadFileType.CMOBILE, UploadFileType.CMOBAPP],
    'sk': [UploadFileType.POPULATION, UploadFileType.PROBABILITY, UploadFileType.REACH]
}
```